# If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n $ converges for $|x| < R$ , then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^n $ converges for $|x| < R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have the following statement:

If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n $ converges for $|x| < R$ , then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^n $ converges for $|x| < R$ as well.

I couldn't find  a counterexample, so I guess this is true , but I would like to get some hints for how to prove it.

Comment: Root test and $n^{1/n}→ 1$, if I recall correctly.

Comment: So u mean by doing the root test for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^n $ ?

Comment: yeah, and also for the original series (for which you already know converges on $|x|<R$).

Answer (score 2):

Given an $x$ with $|x|<R$ choose $p$, $q$ such that $|x|<p<q<R$. Since $\sum_n a_nq^n$ converges there is an $M>0$ such that $|a_n|q^n\leq M$ for all $n\geq1$. Now we have
$$|n\,a_n x^n|=\bigl(|x|/ p\bigr)^n\cdot n\> \bigl(p/q\bigr)^n\cdot |a_n|q^n\ .$$
Here $|x|/ p=:c<1$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}n \bigl(p/q\bigr)^n=0$, hence $\>n \bigl(p/q\bigr)^n\leq M'$ for all $n\geq1$. This implies
$$|n\,a_n x^n|\leq MM' c^n\qquad(n\geq1)\ ,$$
which is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n+...$$
According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration)
$$f'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+...+na_nx^{n-1}+...$$
And according to the very same article:

> Both of these series have the same radius of convergence as the
>   original one.

And [here is](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/22/differentiating-power-series/) a rather technical paper.

$$xf'(x)=a_1x+2a_2x^2+...+na_nx^n+...$$
$$a_0+xf'(x)=a_0+a_1x+2a_2x^2+...+na_nx^n+...$$
$$a_0+xf'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^n$$

This shows the convergence, with the same radius as the original power series.