# Calculus 2 - Prove Disprove - convergence of Taylor series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I got this question regarding properties of Taylor series.

[image: 4 questions]

I'm stuck on the second question, I believe it is true since the area
of convergence for X is affected by the coefficient and it is not changed..

Is this the way to look at it? i'm not so sure how to adress it.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. Please keep in mind that just posting a list of four questions for us to do for you is *not* an appropriate use of the site.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i'll adjust it

Comment: Hint: Your assumption is basically correct,but that's not a formal proof.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Your answer  to ab,c is yes and follows from definition of Taylor's series: term by term differentiation is permissible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) This is obviously false.

(b) This question has been dealt with [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803957/if-sum-n-0-inftya-nxn-converges-for-x-r-then-sum-n-0-i/1804342#1804342) a few days ago.

(c) Consider the series ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^n\over n^2}}\ $.

(d) It is impossible to have $$x^{3/2}=a_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2+o(x^2)\qquad(x\to0)$$ with a suitable choice of $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$. But a convergent power series expansion would entail this.